# Secondary firebase project in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter

I need two separate environments dev and prod for my flutter app

Regarding the coding part I will use development branch and Master branch to sperate production from development

but regarding firebase I want to have Two firebase projects connected to my flutter and I don't like the flavors way

in flutter core docs they share this code to initialize a second firebase app

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'SecondaryApp',
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
        appId: 'my_appId',
        apiKey: 'my_apiKey',
        messagingSenderId: 'my_messagingSenderId',
        projectId: 'my_projectId'
    )
);
```

this part

```
        apiKey: 'my_apiKey',
        messagingSenderId: 'my_messagingSenderId',
        projectId: 'my_projectId'
```

I can get from firebase project settings

but where do I get the

```
appId: 'my_appId',
```

part?

Is it the same flutter app id from the first firebase project or I am missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The **appId** is the unique identifier for the Firebase app across all of Firebase with a platform-specific so is diferent for android and ios, you can find it at the **Proyect Settings** button > **Your apps** section, to learn more about Firebase Proyect Settings check this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more